# Regex to match all log files matches one pattern

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to write one regex which matches all following filename.

```
acbd1251-sample-tmp-store-tmp-1-application.log
acbd1251-sample-tmp-store-tmp-2-application.log
acbd1251-sample-tmp-store-tmp-3-application.log
acbd1251-sample-zmp-store-zmpstore-01-application.log
acbd1251-sample-zmp-store-zmpstore-02-application.log
```

I have tried following `RegEx`to match above files.

```
$logfile =~ /(\w+)-sample-(tmp|zmp)-store-(tmp|zmpstore)-(\d+)-application.log;
```

When I run following script it is not printing anything.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
my $logfile =~ /(\w+)-sample-(tmp|zmp)-store-(tmp|zmpstore)-(\d+)-application.log/;
my $dir = "C:/test/$logfile";

@files = glob( $dir );
foreach (@files ){
   print $_ . "\n";
}
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: I think it is not a problem with the regex [see here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=955536). You can't combine glob an regexp. You can use grep and readdir instead.

Comment: Include [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`use warnings;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) in EVERY script.  Even the short ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want do define regex then,

```
my $logfile = qr/(\w+)-sample-(tmp|zmp)-store-(tmp|zmpstore)-(\d+)-application.log/;
```

`use warnings` would tell you `Use of uninitialized value $logfile in pattern match` for

```
my $logfile =~ /(\w+)-sample-(tmp|zmp)-store-(tmp|zmpstore)-(\d+)-application.log/;
```

and finally you'll want to filter/grep globed directory,

```
my @files = grep /$logfile/, glob( "C:/test" );
```